RUN poetry install --verbose exception Connection reset by peer
I'm having a problem when I use docker-compose up -build:
=> ERROR [app 10/22] RUN poetry install --verbose -v                                                            117.5s
------
[app 10/22] RUN poetry install --verbose -v:
1.514 Creating virtualenv face-api-VsnhxLU2-py3.8 in /home/dckr/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
2.664 Using virtualenv: /home/dckr/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/face-api-VsnhxLU2-py3.8
2.955 Updating dependencies
2.955 Resolving dependencies...
66.37
66.37 Finding the necessary packages for the current system
66.49
66.49 Package operations: 87 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
66.49
66.50   - Installing numpy (1.23.1)
66.51   - Installing nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12 (12.5.82)
75.01   - Installing filelock (3.15.4)
75.03   - Installing joblib (1.4.2)
75.06   - Installing markupsafe (2.1.5)
75.09   - Installing nvidia-cublas-cu12 (12.1.3.1)
75.13   - Installing nvidia-cusparse-cu12 (12.1.0.106)
75.17   - Installing packaging (24.1)
75.21   - Installing mpmath (1.3.0)
75.24   - Installing pillow (10.4.0)
76.05   - Installing scipy (1.9.3)
76.52   - Installing threadpoolctl (3.5.0)
107.6
107.6   ConnectionResetError
107.6
107.7   [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
107.7
107.7   at /usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py:1128 in read
107.8       1124│         if self._sslobj is None:
107.8       1125│             raise ValueError("Read on closed or unwrapped SSL socket.")
107.8       1126│         try:
107.8       1127│             if buffer is not None:
107.8     → 1128│                 return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
107.8       1129│             else:
107.8       1130│                 return self._sslobj.read(len)
107.8       1131│         except SSLError as x:
107.8       1132│             if x.args[0] == SSL_ERROR_EOF and self.suppress_ragged_eofs:
107.8
107.8 The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:
107.8
107.8
107.8   ProtocolError
107.8
107.8   ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
107.8
107.8   at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py:775 in _error_catcher
107.9        771│                     arg = f"Connection broken: {e!r}"
107.9        772│                 raise ProtocolError(arg, e) from e
107.9        773│
108.0        774│             except (HTTPException, OSError) as e:
108.0     →  775│                 raise ProtocolError(f"Connection broken: {e!r}", e) from e
108.0        776│
108.0        777│             # If no exception is thrown, we should avoid cleaning up
108.0        778│             # unnecessarily.
108.0        779│             clean_exit = True
108.0
108.0 The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:
108.0
108.0
108.0   ChunkedEncodingError
108.0
108.0   ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
108.0
108.0   at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/models.py:822 in generate
108.1        818│             if hasattr(self.raw, "stream"):
108.1        819│                 try:
108.1        820│                     yield from self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True)
108.1        821│                 except ProtocolError as e:
108.1     →  822│                     raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
108.1        823│                 except DecodeError as e:
108.1        824│                     raise ContentDecodingError(e)
108.1        825│                 except ReadTimeoutError as e:
108.1        826│                     raise ConnectionError(e)
108.1
108.1 Cannot install nvidia-cublas-cu12.
108.1
115.4
115.4   ConnectionResetError
115.4
115.4   [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
115.4
115.4   at /usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py:1128 in read
115.5       1124│         if self._sslobj is None:
115.5       1125│             raise ValueError("Read on closed or unwrapped SSL socket.")
115.5       1126│         try:
115.5       1127│             if buffer is not None:
115.5     → 1128│                 return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
115.5       1129│             else:
115.5       1130│                 return self._sslobj.read(len)
115.5       1131│         except SSLError as x:
115.5       1132│             if x.args[0] == SSL_ERROR_EOF and self.suppress_ragged_eofs:
115.5
115.5 The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:
115.5
115.5
115.5   ProtocolError
115.5
115.5   ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
115.5
115.5   at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py:775 in _error_catcher
115.6        771│                     arg = f"Connection broken: {e!r}"
115.6        772│                 raise ProtocolError(arg, e) from e
115.6        773│
115.6        774│             except (HTTPException, OSError) as e:
115.6     →  775│                 raise ProtocolError(f"Connection broken: {e!r}", e) from e
115.6        776│
115.6        777│             # If no exception is thrown, we should avoid cleaning up
115.6        778│             # unnecessarily.
115.6        779│             clean_exit = True
115.6
115.6 The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:
115.6
115.6
115.6   ChunkedEncodingError
115.6
115.6   ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
115.6
115.6   at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/models.py:822 in generate
115.7        818│             if hasattr(self.raw, "stream"):
115.7        819│                 try:
115.7        820│                     yield from self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True)
115.7        821│                 except ProtocolError as e:
115.7     →  822│                     raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
115.7        823│                 except DecodeError as e:
115.7        824│                     raise ContentDecodingError(e)
115.7        825│                 except ReadTimeoutError as e:
115.7        826│                     raise ConnectionError(e)
115.7
115.7 Cannot install nvidia-cusparse-cu12.
115.7
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c poetry install --verbose -v" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

How can I fix this?

My guess is you have a slow network connection and are seeing a timeout - it's taking almost exactly 30s between the last successful package install and the error.

I'd take a look at https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2200

i use this command to run poetry
"RUN poetry install --verbose"
how can i add timeout at

based on the link, I think you can do export PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=300 before you run poetry (but I've not tried it myself)

I tried the command ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=300 but it did not solve the problem, the command RUN poetry install --verbose runs until 114 seconds and the error is as described.

Maybe take a look at https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6009 - there's a comment RUN python3 -m pip config --user set global.timeout 150 (but it's hard to follow, a lot of these PRs seem to have been rejected and it's not clear what does and doesn't work from the comments)

I tried it and the result is still the same error :((

It seems that the timeout command is not useful in this case

There's some other options here https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3219 (poetry config installer.parallel false). None of which seem like great options but the symptoms seem to match your issue closely.

The command RUN poetry config installer.parallel false is used to configure poetry to disable parallel installation helped me to solve this problem, thank you so much

As mentioned, it's a known Poetry issue https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3219, that urllib3 gets connection errors when running inside Docker/Podamn containers.
These Poetry configurations were suggested to resolve it:
# Option 1:
poetry config installer.parallel false

# Option 2:
poetry config installer.max-workers 5

I'm using the first option, and haven't noticed a performance difference with the other option.
